# Will be possible to call directly IDP in SAML?

Tags: saml-2.0, service-provider, idp

Because of xyz reasons, we don't have **Service Provider (SP)** to place SAML login request. So, here my question is will it be possible to login into SAML through **IDP** directly? If it is possible, could you please explain steps? We are using **Webservices**, please remind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IdP can read SAML tokens but only when they are grouped using a profile. A common profile is the browser based WBSSO. So in order to talk to the IdP you need an SP. The SP just groups the SAML tokens into a profile the IdP can understand. Most SAML profiles are browser based but have a look at the ECP profile for non browser access https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/ECP

Comment: Do you have any suggestion, how to configure SAML with Cognos?